How to fetch Raydium Fee rates
I would like to fetch the tradeFeeRate when making a swap on Raydium.

You can fetch the fee config accounts that contain this info using the V2 SDK using https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2/
async function getFeeRates() {
    const feeConfigs = await raydium.api.getCpmmConfigs();

    console.log(feeConfigs);
}
getFeeRates();

which would output the following when on devnet
[
  {
    id: "D4FPEruKEHrG5TenZ2mpDGEfu1iUvTiqBxvpU8HLBvC2",
    index: 0,
    protocolFeeRate: 120000,
    tradeFeeRate: 2500,
    fundFeeRate: 40000,
    createPoolFee: "150000000",
  }, {
    id: "G95xxie3XbkCqtE39GgQ9Ggc7xBC8Uceve7HFDEFApkc",
    index: 1,
    protocolFeeRate: 120000,
    tradeFeeRate: 10000,
    fundFeeRate: 40000,
    createPoolFee: "150000000",
  }, {
    id: "2fGXL8uhqxJ4tpgtosHZXT4zcQap6j62z3bMDxdkMvy5",
    index: 2,
    protocolFeeRate: 120000,
    tradeFeeRate: 20000,
    fundFeeRate: 40000,
    createPoolFee: "150000000",
  }, {
    id: "C7Cx2pMLtjybS3mDKSfsBj4zQ3PRZGkKt7RCYTTbCSx2",
    index: 3,
    protocolFeeRate: 120000,
    tradeFeeRate: 40000,
    fundFeeRate: 40000,
    createPoolFee: "150000000",
  }
]

